# Vertical center an absolutely positioned input field inside its surrounding element

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I simply want to vertically center an input field inside its surrounding DIV, but at the same time all input fields on the page should be horizontally aligned with each other (should have the same `left` value, if you will).

Here's an example page of the problem:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.inputClass {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  /* top: 50%; transform: translate(0, -50%); */
  /* not working as I need */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      Some text
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Some more text
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired result (blue rim by Firebug):
[image]

Comment: Do you have an image of the desired result?

Comment: @Paulie_D, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group inputs+labels in fieldsets and then use the labels for moving the inputs towards the center,

try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  /*resets UA*/
}
 /*can use label to move inputs right*/
label {
 width:40%;
 display:inline-block;
 padding-right :15px;
 text-align:right
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <label for='one'>Some text</label>
      <input id='one' type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label for='two'>Some more text</label>
      <input id='two' type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that, what's the fieldset good for though? I can't see a difference between fieldset and div here.

Comment: @jaySon fieldset  is a specific form related tag that's used for grouping form elements, in general form and form related elements have some specialized properties and attributes; in  your case you can do the same thing with regular divs

Answer (score 1):

Put the text in a `label` (this is good practice anyway) and use inline block to position the elements beside each other. You can then give the `label` a width as required:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.wrapper label {
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;  
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.wrapper input {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="field1">Some text</label>
      <input id="field1" type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="field2">Some more text</label>
      <input id="field2" type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, had to mark someone's answer as THE answer. However, yours is just as good.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent way to do this (in my opinion) would be using the table tag in HTML to organise the input fields and the labels. I would then use the "valign" property and set it to "TOP" e.g.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="TOP">
      Some text
    </td>
    <td valign="TOP">
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="TOP">
      Some more text
    </td>
    <td valign="TOP">
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The valign="TOP" assigned to the TD will make it be at the top of the cell in the table. This will ensure that they will be vertically and horizontally aligned with each other.

Comment: Last time I checked, it was discouraged to use the `table` tag for formatting.

Comment: That's debatable among HTML programmers, however, it seems to work without needing to change the padding in order to get it into the right places which could be problematic in regards to different browsers and sizes.

Comment: I believe that the reason some people are against it would be that it vertically aligns to the center of the cell which looks rather ugly. That's why I use the valign property to set all contents in the cells to the top.

Comment: I'd rather say, the reason why people are against it is because it's an abuse of the tag. And `valign` is obsolete as of HTML 5 (read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement#Specifications)).

Comment: I've just posted another answer which doesn't use the table tag, although it will require BootStrap.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer without using the table tag:

```html
<style>
  li {
    width: 120px;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>
      <input type="text">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Some more text</li>
    <li>
      <input type="text">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This would be used using BootStrap in order to list it in line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a framework named "DevExtreme" for the whole project, which is in conflict with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to put all the form labels in a div with class "col-left" & the input fields in a div with class "col-right". Both these are vertically middle aligned (vertical-align: middle) & the left column holding the labels have an equal width setting.

Please find below the complete solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.col-left, .col-right {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
}
.col-left {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="col-left">Some text</div>
    <div class="col-right">
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-left">Some more text</div>
    <div class="col-right">
      <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```